# Acting on a different display when using SSH

Tags: ssh, centos, display

I am connecting to a Linux CentOS 2.6 computer via SSH wit the display deported on my screen (using MobaXterm).
It is also possible to access to this computer "physically".

However, I would like a way to inform people that may want to access "physically" to the computer that I am currently using it via SSH.

One way would be for them to make `who` in a terminal and see whether someone is connected from another computer. However, I don't want them to have to check this manually each time (they may - and will - forget this check).

Thus, I would like a way to open a window on THEIR display (i.e. the screen plugged to the computer) with a message for them. Somthing like a text into gedit would do the work.

Can I do that? Can I open an application on a different display than mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I do that? Can I open an application on a different display than mine?

Yes, *if* you have the appropriate permissions.  For example, on a desktop where you are the only current user with a GUI, try switching to a console (e.g., via alt-ctl-F4), log in as the same user, and try:

```
xterm -display 0:0
```

Your mileage may vary with regard to the display id (see comments), which is actually a [network address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1210332/1151724). Presuming xterm is installed and there are no errors (note this is a foreground process, so don't ctrl-c or otherwise interrupt this from the console), you should now be able to switch back the GUI and find an xterm floating somewhere.

Most GUI applications should accept this `-display` option.  You can do the same thing via `ssh`.  If there are multiple X servers running, the displays are usually numbered starting with 0:0, then 0:1 -- at least, that's how they are if they are all using the same physical card and monitor; I'm not sure how it works if you have multiple X servers running simultaneously connected to separate physical displays (perhaps 0:0, 1:0,...).

Again, note that you need appropriate permissions to do this.  The superuser can start an application on anyone's display, but if you are just normal user `bob`, you will not be allowed to launch something on normal user `sue`'s desktop.

You can also start an X server via `ssh` and launch applications on it this way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is has worked, but I had to type the command `xterm -display :0.0` instead of `xterm -display 0:0` you answered. I'm not sure if it is a typo or if there is a difference (looks like a typo to me).

Comment: `-display 0:0` works for me on a local console -- and in fact, `:0.0` fails with a "No protocol" error.  Lo and behold, it's actually a network address...there's a great discussion of that **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1210332/1151724)**; I've edited a link to that into the answer too.

Comment: Ok I'll check that! Thank you again for your help here :)